# JSF Datatable current Page Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to display the current page of a datatable outside of the table (I actually need it for paging a the items on a google maps component). How can I get the current page of the datatable?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0):

In tomahawk you can use dataScroller pageIndexVar (only inside datascroller component)

```
<t:dataScroller for="data_table" pageIndexVar="current_page">
   <h:outputText value="#{current_page}" />
</t:dataScroller>
```

http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_dataScroller.html